# Cuerrent months ex-dividend date versus the next months ex-dividend date?

Tags: ex-dividend-date

If I know the current months ex-dividend date is there any way to determine the next months ex-dividend date?

Comment: Some muutal funds declare dividends on the "same day" each month e.g. the _last_ day of the month, which could be any _numerical_ day of the month from the 28th through the 31st, depending on the month and the year. Stocks rarely declare dividends each month, and bonds pay interest, not dividends (bond mutual funds do pay dividends, though).

Comment: Why does it matter? Dividends are usually a wash from a value perspective (the instrument drops in value by the amount of the dividend) so what do you need to know the next dividend date for?

Comment: @DilipSarwate: although bond fund distributions are often labelled dividends, they are actually distributions of interest (less operating expenses), and don't get the lower tax rates that apply to most stock dividends in US.

Answer (score 2):

Some ETFs, ETNs and funds pay monthly dividends.  Not many stocks do so other than preferred stocks.  Some will pay on the same date every month.  Some will pay within a day or two on either side of last month's date.

Fidelity offers a screener which shows historical dividend and distribution amounts and ex-div dates:

https://screener.fidelity.com/ftgw/etf/goto/snapshot/distributions.jhtml?symbols=SPY

Enter the symbol of your stock and see if it has consistently paid on the same date or if it has varied.